# Выпадающее меню перекрывается картинкой

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование

Всем привет, столкнулся с такой проблемой. 
При установки подписи на картинку и придании свойства position: relative тегу figure список выпадающего меню перекрывается картинкой.
Хочется оставить подпись на картинке.

Ответ на вопрос нашел пользователь MoJlo4HuK добавив строчку кода для тега

```
nav ul ul {
z-index:20;
}
```

За что ему отдельное спасибо

`[CodePen]`[CodePen](https://codepen.io/daDast/pen/WEJOor)

Comment: Перенеси код в вопрос в виде сниппета.

Comment: Там очень большой кусок кода и добавление его бессмысленно,  или из за того что нет кусочка кода ссылка на CodePen не отображается?

Answer (score 0):

[Про z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/z-index)

```
nav ul ul {
    z-index: 20;
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, может вы знаете хорошую статью про z-index ? можно и на английском.

Comment: так я добавил ссылочку ж "Про z-index" , там подробно все описано

Comment: Извиняюсь, не заметил, впервые пользуюсь этим сайтом=)